# Control Picklist value for a specific user

Tags: community, picklist, administration, user, object

Is it possisble to control picklist values to specific user..?

Eg: If I add new picklist value to Account Type, that value should be available only for a specific user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. At least, not directly.

Picklist values can be made available at the Record Type level. However, that's really not applicable here, where you want to control the accessibility of a single value to a single user.

Instead, you'd typically implement a Validation Rule on the Account to allow only specified users to save records which have this value, or to set this value on a record.

The best pattern for this type of validation rule is to create a new [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5), say `AllowsAllTypes`. Then, in your validation rule, you can do something like this:

```
AND(NOT($Permission.AllowsAllTypes), ISCHANGED(Type), ISPICKVAL(Type, "Restricted Type"))
```

That would prevent any user without the custom permission on their profile or permission set from changing an Account's Type to "Restricted Type". They'd be able to see it, but they would not be permitted to update or create an account with that value.